# Running a script (multiple statements) using the Mysql gem in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have the following query script in a file, my_query.sql

```
select * from my_table;
delete from my_other_table where id > 5;
select * from my_other_table;
```

I'm trying to execute this via the 'mysql' gem in Ruby I'm running into 2 key problems

1. The query has multiple statements, and the ruby gem requires that I query them one at a time using the .query(...) method.
2. The query has multiple select statements, and the gem returns a hash, so I'm unsure whether it will return multiple result sets.

Ideally, in unix/bash, I could just do

```
mysql my_schema < my_query.sql > my_out_file.txt
```

This would just run the entire script at once (solving problem #1), and would just print as plain text the results of all select statements (solving problem #2).

Does Ruby have a similar option to just run a query file and have the entire output dumped to file?

Note: I'm aware I can shell out or use system(...) to execute this, but that's not an acceptable option here. Any way I can get this done via the mysql gem (or a similar gem)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get multiple statements as follows. Note the flag that you have to pass it in order to enable multiple statements.

```
conn  = Mysql2::Client.new(:host     => my_hostname,
                           :database => my_db,
                           :username => my_user, 
                           :password => my_password,
                           :flags    => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sending each statement separately is fine. They are unique in SQL because they are separated by semicolons ("`;`").

You'll get an array of hashes if multiple rows match your query. You can iterate over them using `each` or `map` if you want to transform them. It's one of the most common things you'll do with database access from inside a language, whether it's Ruby, Python, Perl or Java.

I highly recommend you look into using the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) gem as your interface to the database. It's an ORM, acting as a nice interface layer between your code and SQL and the DBM. You can write your queries programmatically, which is a big win. Instead of having to write SQL, you let Sequel generate the queries for you.From my experience, it does a very good job writing efficient code; You have to go out of your way to make it do the wrong thing.

The second thing that it brings to the table, is a very easy path to migration between other DBM types, from SQLite, to PostgreSQL or Oracle, along with a bunch of others.

We use it exclusively at work, and I use it for all my DB work for my own personal code. Start with the [Readme](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) to learn more.

---

If all your queries are on one line, you can use:

```
File.foreach('sql_queries.sql') do |li|
  puts li
end
```

If they aren't all on one line, you can try using something like the above, but modify the [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to pass in a new line-end character. If you use `;` Ruby will consider the semicolon to be the end of lines, grabbing each SQL statement in its entirety:

```
File.foreach('sql_queries.sql', ';') do |li|
```

Comment: Thanks! I have heard of the Sequel gem (and will keep it in mind for future use), but I'll likely stick with the familiar Mysql gem for now.

I guess if everything is properly terminated by semicolons, I can just parse my queryfile into different queries by using the seimicolon as a delimiter, then run each piece separately. I guess I could also check after each query whether a result was returned, and if so, print to file.

Comment: I'll add some sample code showing how to split the file, assuming you don't have semicolons anywhere but at the end of the lines.